# Create styled component based on other component with props

Tags: styled-components

Adding a style to `P` works nicely:

```
const Quotation = styled(P)`
    &::before, &::after {
        content: '"';
    }
`;
```

But what I want to do is add a style to `P` with the prop `italic=true` passed to it. Something like:

```
const Quotation = styled(P italic=true)`
    &::before, &::after {
        content: '"';
    }
`;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your component like :

```
interface Props { children: any , italic ?: boolean }

const P = styled.p<Props>`
    // Style you added.
    font-style: ${({ italic }) => italic ? 'italic' : 'normal'  };
`;

const Quotation = styled(P)`
    &::before, &::after {
        content: '"';
    }
    // Additional style.
`;
```

**Usage**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Quotation italic={true}> Hello World </Quotation>
        </div>
    )  
}
```

When you extend a component with `Styled(ComponentA)` you inherit `props`.

However in your case, pass props is maybe unnecessary, you can just do :

```
const P = styled.p`
     // style you added.
`;

const Quotation = styled(P)`
    &::before, &::after {
        content: '"';
    }
    font-style: italic; 
    // Additional style.
`;
```